# Unable to connect to specific network with either wifi or ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

since around two days ago I am unable to connect to my home wifi network at all, but can connect to other networks such as my phone hotspot. When using wifi, it always comes up with “can’t connect to this network” and with ethernet, it is either as an unidentified network or just stuck as identifying. I have tried basically all suggestions given when searching up the error including uninstalling drivers and even reinstalling windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be a DHCP issue, given that similar problems are happening on both WiFi and Ethernet. Also check the ethernet cable and socket.

2 options

**1) Router reset - potentially destructive!!**

You may find it easiest to hardware reset your router using the reset button at the back - this should hopefully reset the router configuration to the default which should fix issues 99% of the time. However, you will need to reconfigure all your settings (e.g. network name, password, WAN connection settings etc). You will almost certainly be able to find precise instructions on how to do this for your specific model of router with an internet search.

**2) Try a static address - may not work, especially if DHCP is not the problem**

Alternatively, you can set a static address for your network interface on Windows and see if you are then able to connect to the router to fix the problem. See this answer on how to configure a static address:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272961/how-to-set-a-static-ip-address-in-windows-10

Choose a known good IP address. Domestic routers commonly use the 192.168.1.0/24 private subnet. You may be able to use an address like `192.168.1.99`. Try a few to see whether you have any luck

If this is successful, try connecting to the admin interface to track down and fix the problem.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the reply and sorry for the late response. I should mention that my PC is the only device in the house that cannot connect to the internet, so my parents didn’t want for me to reset the router. Unfortunately, a static IP was also unsuccessful. I tried to restart the DHCP service but error 5 came up every time asking for administrator privileges even though my account has administrator status.

Comment: Try this: https://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=19483

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far, unfortunately that doesnt seem to work either. I have a feeling that my Ethernet port might just be completely broken as my pc cannot detect the three cables I used. I managed to get internet via USB tethering with a Samsung phone but I am unable to use it all the time as it was my dad’s. Could that signal anything?

Comment: The pins can get damaged. You could purchase a USB ethernet adaptor and use a known-working ethernet cable. But you said that WiFi also wasn't working.